# Remove Loader in When Click Cancel in Angular 4

Tags: angular, loader, angular-services, angular-forms, angular-observable

I have this npm package called ngx-loading. I have to set this.loading = true and this.loading = false to make it show and not to show. The problem comes when i use the alert in javascript. The alert shows "ok"and "cancel". When i click "ok" the loader disappears while if i click "cancel" and "x" it still appears? How can i make the loader disappears when i click the cancel or x button? Here's what i've done below.

> TS

```
onUpdate(form: NgForm) {
  this.loading = true;

  name =  form.value.name,

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to update?')) {
    this.subscription = this.prodService.update(name)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
       this.loading = false;
       console.log(data); 
     },
     error => {
       this.loading = false;
       console.log(error);
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an else condition when the user clicks cancel.

```
onUpdate(form: NgForm) {
  this.loading = true;

  name =  form.value.name,

  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to update?')) {
    this.subscription = this.prodService.update(name)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
       this.loading = false;
       console.log(data); 
     },
     error => {
       this.loading = false;
       console.log(error);
     });
  } else {
    this.loading = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below :

```
onUpdate(form: NgForm) {
  this.loading = true;

  name =  form.value.name,
var _confirm = confirm('Are you sure you want to update?');
  if (_confirm ) {
    this.subscription = this.prodService.update(name)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
       this.loading = false;
       console.log(data); 
     },
     error => {
       this.loading = false;
       console.log(error);
     });
  }
else {
 this.loading = false;
}
}
```